# how to implement UNION operation between stream and batch data

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, stream-processing

Apparently Spark Structure Streaming does not support UNION operation between stream and batch data, based on [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala).

I wonder why is that? Is it a difficult thing to implement?
I need to execute some processing (including UNION operation) between a stream and a table in a real-time setting. Do you have any Suggestion? 
I already have spark in my cluster.